# SavonClient not able to access wsdl through proxy server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, soap, amazon-ec2, proxy, savon

Context : I have to call an externalService, which lies outside the environments hosted by us on AWS-EC2. This externalService requires IP Addresses to be whitelisted before accessing it. Since EC2 hosts IPAddresses are not guaranteed to be same and can change while replacing hosts, we decided to route the API calls through a proxy-server.

We are doing the same for some other externalServices calls as well, but those are all REST based, so we have not faced any problems while calling their APIs using rest-client or net/http.

Now, this time it's a SOAP Service and we are using Savon to access it. 
I am able to download the url using "curl" on proxy server host but if I access wsdl through proxy-server from SavonClient, it fails. It gives 403 forbidden error.

```
irb(main):102:0* client = Savon.client do |variable|
irb(main):103:1* variable.proxy 'http://172.31.50.91:3128'
irb(main):104:1> variable.wsdl 'https://<some_url_here>'
irb(main):105:1> end
=> #<Savon::Client:……>>>
irb(main):106:0> 
irb(main):107:0* client.operations
Net::HTTPServerException: 403 "Forbidden"
```

For other services which do not require IP whitelisting SavonClient works, whether or not proxy-server address is provided.

Any help will be appreciated. I have been struck here for long.

Thanks,